# How to set up ZfcUser with Doctrine ORM on Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, git, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, composer-php

How can I set up ZfcUser module with Skeleton Application on ZF2, the first time, while using recommended practices?

Answer (score 2):

So, basically ...

```
cd (main workspace)
```

Install latest composer from the get go

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php --
```

Download latest ZendSkeletonApplication

```
php composer.phar create-project -sdev --repository-url="https://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application MyGreatApp
```

Move latest composer into the tree (overwriting one that was there)

```
mv composer.phar ./MyGreatApp
cd MyGreatApp
```

Check/Modify your existing .gitignore file within `MyGreatApp`

- remove `composer.lock` ([why](http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md))
- add `vendor` ([why](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file))

Remove git submodules ([why](http://somethingsinistral.net/blog/git-submodules-are-probably-not-the-answer/))

```
git rm .gitsubmodules
```

Initialize repository:

```
git init
git add .
git commit –m “my initial commit of ZendSkeletonApplication”
```

Take a breather.

**Now then, install your modules**

This one won't hurt during development (optional):

```
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-developer-tools:dev-master
cp vendor/zendframework/zend-developer-tools/config/zenddevelopertools.local.php.dist config/autoload/zdt.local.php
```

Install Doctrine: ([note on composer versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14816988/2883328))

```
php composer.phar require doctrine/doctrine-orm-module:~0.7
```

Set up Database Connection Settings for Doctrine ORM:

Namely, go to [Doctrine Connection Settings](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule#connection-settings), and copy/paste/modify the example configuration file content into your `config/autoload/doctrine.orm.local.php` file within `MyGreatApp` folder.

`*.local.php` files will not be tracked by git as per ZF2, and will remain local to your personal repo.  In this case, it is so DB-specific data is not copied to the main repo.  You will have to recreate those files for any new repo you create.

Install Yer Zfc Components:

```
php composer.phar require zf-commons/zfc-user:~0.1
php composer.phar require zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm:~0.1
```

You do not need to create custom configuration files for the above two modules to work.  ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14781304/2883328))

**It is time:**

Set up your Modules in `config/application/application.config.php`, something like

```
'modules' => array(
    'ZendDeveloperTools',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    'ZfcBase',
    'ZfcUser',
    'ZfcUserDoctrineORM',
    'Application',
),
```

Try using Doctrine to set up your schema:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql
```

You may want to set up your database and users accordingly for this.  And if that looks okay, do:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

Now, go set up your localhost stuff and VirtualHost settings and go to `http://localhost/MyGreatApp
/user` and it should just work.

Proceed as normal.  Comment, if it worked for you.